# Login on a website and then access another section of that site

Tags: c++, session, curl, session-cookies, libcurl

I managed to login on my desired [site](http://www.expert-monitor.ro/) with curl and then I tried to access a [section](http://www.expert-monitor.ro/LexMonitorMBM/comercial/clientextern/extension/open_viewer.php?res=P1%2F2013%2F0001) of my site with the same handle and it doesn't recognize my current session.

I set curl to handle itself cookies.

```
curl_easy_setopt( curlHandleMO, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "" );
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: I used FireBug in Firefox to see how a POST request on my desired site looks and I created a header request just like the one Firefox used.

```
struct curl_slist *header=NULL; 
header = curl_slist_append(header,"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
header = curl_slist_append(header,"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
header = curl_slist_append(header,"Accept-Language: en-us,ro-ro;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6,en-gb;q=0.4,en;q=0.2");
header = curl_slist_append(header,"Connection:  keep-alive");
header = curl_slist_append(header,"Cookie:  __utma=111401936.1442146463.1383320644.1384439040.1384441847.12; __utmz=111401936.1384276584.7.3.utmcsr=expert-monitor.ro|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/LexMonitorMBM/comercial/clientextern/autentic.php; Clientextern=klhttfmf1jt2v7c11efcv4lqn4; __utmc=111401936; __utmb=111401936.9.10.1384441847");
header = curl_slist_append(header,"DNT: 1");
header = curl_slist_append(header,"Host:    www.expert-monitor.ro");
header = curl_slist_append(header,"Referer: http://www.expert-monitor.ro/LexMonitorMBM/comercial/clientextern/login.php?succes=0");
header = curl_slist_append(header,"User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");

curl_easy_setopt(curlHandleMO, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't add comments, yet. You can refer to the following question and answer: [How to manage a simple PHP session using C++ cURL (libcurl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203990/how-to-manage-a-simple-php-session-using-c-curl-libcurl)

Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I found this article yesterday too but it doesn't work for me.. Still doesn't recognize my session.